# Isomorphism between two finitley presented groups which are not finite

Tags: group-isomorphism, gap, group-presentation, infinite-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

I am looking for an isomorphism between the two following groups (infinite groups) ( probably by GAP to show that there is an isomorphism between $f$ and $g$)

$$f=\langle  a,b,c ~| ~ bab^{-1}a^{-1},cac^{-1}a^{-1}\rangle $$

$$g=\langle a,b,c ~|~ bcb^{-1}c^{-1},cac^{-1}a^{-1}\rangle$$

The generators $a$, $b$, $c$ are the same in two groups, I am not sure but guess, there should be an isomorphism which takes $a$ to $c$?

Comment: Your guess is right on.  Are you just having trouble showing that $\varphi : f \to g$ defined on the generators as $\varphi(a) = c, \varphi(b) = b, \varphi(c) = a$ gives an isomorphism?  If so, it may help to first show $f \cong <a> \times <b,c>.$

Comment: Yes, Thanks, Brian. Got it! I was just wondering if there is a command in GAP to get this, but probably much easier than using GAP cause it is clear manually!

Comment: There isn't really a GAP command for this -- generically the question of isomorphism of finitely presented groups is very hard.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sure $$<a,b,c|bcb^{-1}c^{-1},cac^{-1}a^{-1}>\ =\ <a,b,c|bcb^{-1}c^{-1}, (cac^{-1}a^{-1})^{-1}>$$